# Objective-c Is super init a class method or instance method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class

I am new in objective c. I understand that `-init()` is an `instance method` and return an object
e.g. `myObj＝[myObj init];` will return an object `myObj.`

However, if `self ＝[super init];` normally `super refer to parent` class e.g. `NSObject` which is a `class, not instance`.

So, `Is -init() instance method or class method for super init?`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init` is an instance method. The fact that you call it on `super` does not change it.

Keep in mind that `super` does not represent the class of your object, but your object seen as an instance of its parent class in the class hierarchy.

And you never call `myObj＝[myObj init];` — you call `myObj = [[MyObj alloc] init]`. Notice the case difference between `myObj` (a variable) and `MyObj` (the class of which this variable is an instance).

Comment: So, what is the instance object of the parent class i.e. In NSObject class? There is no instance created in parent class normally!

Comment: That's the concept of object-oriented programming. When you declare the class `MyObj` as a descendent class of `NSObject`, it means that each time you create an instance of `MyObj`, it *also* is an instance of `NSObject` itself. Let's say inheritance is like genetics: male humans are "subclasses" of humans, which are subclasses of primates, which are subclasses of mammals, which are subclass of animals. Just because you're a "male human", means you're also a "human", a "primate", a "mammal" and an "animal".

Comment: you *could* do `myObj = [myObj init];` For example, you could do alloc and init in separate steps e.g. `myObj = [MyObj alloc]; myObj = [myObj init];` You can also use `init` outside of initialization if you want -- it just might not do what you want

Comment: Technically you can, but I've never, ever seen cases where it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `init` is used after `alloc` in this way:

```
MyObject* obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

and `alloc` create the object instance, so `init` is an instance method, and when you override it, it's good habit to call always the parent class `init`.

Try to read this [article](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-initializers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Super is referring to the methods of the parent class in the current **object**. Calling `super init` will call the method `init` on the current object (`self`), but will use the implementation of the super class. So **no** - `init` is not a static method (this would be visible due to a `+` before the init method). you can call `super whatMethodYouWantFromSuperclass` even though it is not static. Static methods are not called on an object (`self`) but on a class (`[NSObject yourStaticMethod]`).